# Does software update really get me the latest version of the OS?

Tags: upgrade

I suspect if I have a computer running an outdated version of Ubuntu, I need to download and install a new OS. I probably cannot just boot the old system and run software update. SW update can't update the kernel, etc. Am I right?

Comment: What version are you running now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it can.

When you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, it will install all updates for **your version of Ubuntu**, which include both software packages and kernel updates. So, for example, if you have Ubuntu 14.04, you may update your kernel to the latest *3.x* version (get minor updates). But not to the *4.x* (major update) version (though, actually there are methods to do that too).

If you want to get the newest updates, you may try to upgrade your Ubuntu version by typing: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. But be careful with that.

---

If you have an Ubuntu version earlier than 12.04 LTS, you won't be able to get updates at all, except that you may actually do a release upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu. For example, if you have 10.04, you may update to 12.04, then to 14.04 and finally to 16.04. One major dist upgrade at a time.

Thanks to Zeiss for pointing this out in a comment.

Comment: If you want both, and are using a standard desktop, you can run `update-manager`.

Comment: On the other hand, if the outdated version is EOL (like, say, 12.04, or even 10.04), all support has been discontinued and you will get no updates at all.  You *will* get errors about repositories not found, of course, which ought to be a clue.  To be clear, this answer is *correct* for versions still supported (at present, that's 14.04, 16.04, and 16.10 only), but other versions have no support, even for security updates.